# Deleting all greetings and footers from email text. What is the approach?

Tags: python, text

I have thousands of emails (dataset) and one step in a preprocessing pipeline is a deletion of all greetings (For example: Dear Sir and Madam, Dear Team X etc.) and footers (like: Best Regards, Sincerely etc.)

I see 3 approaches of solving the problem:

1. Define all possible Greetings and Footers variants and using something like `if word in set_of_greetings or word in set_of_footers -> delete word` using `string.replace()` function.
2. Train/use pre-trained neural network in order to classify NER (named entity recognition) "greeting" and "footer" and than delete all footers and greetings.
3. Combination of this 2 approaches

With the first approach, the difficulty is to find and store all possible forms of greetings (emails are mostly in german, but some are in english)

With second approach, the difficulty is to find a dataset or labeling existing emails. It might take days or maybe even more.

What would be the best approach in your opinion and how would you tackle the problem using this approach?

Each email is just a text(string).

Comment: Does it matter if your software makes mistakes?

Comment: @StephenC it does. The more reliable approach the better.

Comment: What error rate is acceptable?   Put your answers into the question.

Comment: @StephenC in this case it's not that critical. I would say, if 90-95% of the cases will be covered -> I will be satisfied.

Comment: What about false positives / removals of non-greetings?

Comment: @StephenC that's not desirable. It's better to have more false negatives, than false positives

Comment: IMO - the best approach is to try the simplest approach first and see how well it works.  You now have some criteria by which you can judge success.  However, any predictions we would / could make on what solution will give the best results is basically guesswork.